# EF7 dnx46 Whats the equivalent of EntityFunctions.AddMinutes

Tags: entity-framework

Simple question, i wish to use the equivalent of EntityFunctions.AddMinutes in EF7 - how do i achieve this?

For example - whats the equivalent of this in EF7

```
   _ef7context.Table.Where(s => s.Time >= fromDate && EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(s.Time, 60 <= toDate);
```

What do i need to import into my project.json?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412671%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not yet in EFCore (formerly EF7).